# Sending json object but POST method not supported

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to send a json object to a specified url using **POST** method.
But when I run the code the firebug shows the error as **Error 501 method POST not supported**
Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/data/' + name + ".json",
            contentType: 'text/json',
            data: {"name": "XYZ",
                   "city": "ABC"
                  },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("sucessful");
            }
});
```

I also tried "PUT" method but no luck.
Any idea or alternate option for this???

Comment: What web server do you use? Do you have any proxies between you and target web server?

Comment: Actually I am running a simple python HTTP server on my local machine

Comment: Does your server support POST? You are trying to post json, if server doesn't support POST, it may throw the error POST method not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually I am running a simple python HTTP server on my local machine

So you need to need to reconfigure it (if it can handle `POST`) or choose another server

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on the server - it **does not accept specific types of requests**. It is not actually the "*problem*", it is the way this service seems to work.

But there is one type of request you did not mention. The most common request type is **`GET`**. Try it and if it does not help, then talk to the people that prepared the script on the server, so they can give you some tips (eg. maybe the message is fake and it will work correctly with correct data sent to the server).

Here is the code that should be the **complete solution** (changed only type of the request):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/data/' + name + ".json",
    contentType: 'text/json',
    data: {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "city": "ABC"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("sucessful");
    }
});
```

Comment: With GET method it is working fine, the problem is with POST and PUT methods.

Comment: @AmitSharma: The server does not support these requests, as you mentioned, didn't you? I understand that the response from the server is "`Error 501 method POST not supported`", correct? Then there is nothing you can do on client side, except making a request of correct type. `GET` is this correct one type. There is also one called `DELETE`, but I really think you should think about what you are trying to achieve. You have the solution, use it.